# How to merge two different models in one model and show output in one view?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core

Here is my model

```
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int? MainSurveyId { get; set; }
        public string Question { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public IList<xxAnswer> answers { get; set; }
    }
```

This is my controller, notice that I separated the `var question` and `var answer`

```
 [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult CompareCompetitors(string[] comps, int Surveyid)
        {
           var model = new CompareCompetitorAnswers();
           foreach( var item in comps){
               model.competitorNames.Add( new xxCompetitor() { CompetitorName = item} );
           }

            var questions = _context.SurveyQuestions.ToList().Where(x => x.MainSurveyId == Surveyid);
            foreach (var q in questions){
                model.questions.Add(new xxQuestion { Question = q.Question});
            }

             var answers = _context.SurveyCompetitorAnswer.ToList().Where(x => x.MainSurveyId == Surveyid);
            foreach (var a in answers){
                model.answers.Add(new xxAnswer { Answer = a.Answer});
            }


            return View(model);
            //return string.Join(",", comps); // check if it works with this. ph wait. i think correct. sorry. i will try now.
        }
```

Here is my view but it shows an error in `@foreach (var a in q.answers)`.

```
 <tbody>
         @foreach (var q in Model.questions)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td scope="row">
                        @q.Question
                    </td>
                    @foreach (var a in q.answers)
                    {
                        <td scope="row">
                            @a.Answer
                        </td>    
                    }


                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
```

I want the answers to be posted beside the results. They are in different database tables. But it output errors at `@foreach (var a in q.answers)`.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out how:

```
<tbody>      
    @foreach (var q in Model.questions)
    {
      <tr>
      <td scope="row">
        @q.Question
      </td>
      @foreach (var a in Model.answers.Where(x => x.SurveyQuestionId == q.Id))
      {
         <td scope="row">
           @a.Answer
         </td>    
      }
      </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

I didn't use the

```
public IList<xxAnswer> answers { get; set; }
```

I just used:

```
@foreach (var a in Model.answers.Where(x => x.SurveyQuestionId == q.Id))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little bit late, however I hope that will help you optimize your model approach.

Assume this is your simplified model:

```
public class AnswerModel
{
   // Omitted for simplicity
}

public class QuestionModel
{
    public List<AnswerModel> Answers { get; set; } = new List<AnswerModel>();
}
```

You shouldn't do *.ToList()* before *.Where()* because you're actually materialize the entire entity (aka table). 
It's better if you use a join to do your query or if you prefer you could use the NavigationProperty, if you have one, to track the collection of **Answers** related to your **Question**.

[LINQ basics](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/ef/core/querying/basic)

However I use your approach with two separated query:

```
var model = new List<QuestionModel>();
var questions = _context.SurveyQuestions.Where(x => x.MainSurveyId == Surveyid).ToList();
var answers = _context.SurveyCompetitorAnswer.Where(x => x.MainSurveyId == Surveyid).ToList();
foreach (var q in questions){
    var qModel = new QuestionModel();
    qModel.Answers.AddRange(answers.Where(x => x.SurveyQuestionId == q.Id).ToList());
    model.Add(qModel);
}
```

And with a more simple and aggregated model:

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (var q in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td scope="row">
                @q.Question
            </td>
            @foreach (var a in q.Answers)
            {
                <td scope="row">
                    @a.Answer
                </td>    
            }
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

If you would share your entities, we could optimize the query!

**Happy coding!**